# Saving a split string to an arraylist using LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq, arraylist

I have some code that takes a string and processes it by splitting it into words, and giving the count of each word.

The trouble is it only returns `void`, because I am only able to print to the screen after the processing is done. Is there any way I can save the results in an `arraylist`, so that that I can return it to the method that called it?

The current code:

```
message.Split(' ').Where(messagestr => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(messagestr))
               .GroupBy(messagestr => messagestr).OrderByDescending(groupCount => groupCount.Count())
               .Take(20).ToList().ForEach(groupCount => Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", groupCount.Key, groupCount.Count()));
```

Thank you.

Comment: if you store in an arraylist, how will you know which count is for which word? don't you want to use some data structure like a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, by calling `Take(20)` you just take the first 20 words and put the others away. So, if you want all the results, remove it.
After that, you can do it like this:

```
var words = message.Split(' ').
               Where(messagestr => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(messagestr)).
               GroupBy(messagestr => messagestr).
               OrderByDescending(groupCount => groupCount.Count()).                 
               ToList();
words.ForEach(groupCount => Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", groupCount.Key, groupCount.Count()));
```

To put the results into some other data structure, you can use one of these ways:

```
var w = words.SelectMany(x => x.Distinct()).ToList(); //Add this line to get all the words in an array
// OR Use Dictionary
var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(var item in words)
{
    dic.Add(item.Key, item.Count());
}
```

Comment: i was hoping i could save the results into an arrayList. Thank you

Comment: @ana: So, accept an answer or if the solution isn't there, edit your question and explain the solution to solve your problem. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var wordCountList = message.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .GroupBy(messagestr => messagestr)
    .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
    .Take(20) //or take the whole
    .Select(grp => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(grp.Key, grp.Count()))
    .ToList(); //return wordCountList

//usage
wordCountList.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", item.Key, item.Value));
```

If you want, you can return the `wordCountList` which is a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` containing all the words and their counts in descending order.

How you can use that, is also shown in the last line.

And rather than taking `first 20` from the list, if you want to take the whole, remove this `.Take(20)` part.